# AsyncTask makes app crash

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the queryAppIcon() method that queries and stores images in the array appIconDrawable. However, I'm only getting blank images pop up for a few seconds before the app crashes (if I use appIconDrawable[1] = d to test in `processFinish`) and if I use appIconDrawable[i] = d, the app just crashes. I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I sent up the for loop in the `queryAppIcon()` and how it connects with the AsyncTask, but I'm not sure what it is

This is the relevant code inside the ViewActivity:

```
// global vars
final Drawable[] appIconDrawable = null;
int i;

public Drawable[] queryAppIcon() throws ParseException, IOException {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AndroidStoreContent");
    query.whereExists("appIcon");
    List<ParseObject> ParseResult = query.find();
    // initialize Drawable array
    final Drawable[] appIconDrawable = new Drawable[ParseResult.size()];

    for (i = 0; i < ParseResult.size(); i++) {
        ParseFile pf = (ParseFile) ParseResult.get(i).get("appIcon");
        startDownload(pf);
    }
    return appIconDrawable;
}

public void startDownload(ParseFile pf) {
    new DownloadImageTask(this).execute(pf);
}

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<ParseFile, Void, Drawable> {

    private AsyncResponse ar;

    DownloadImageTask(AsyncResponse ar) {
        this.ar = ar;
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(ParseFile... pf) {
        return fetchDrawable(pf[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        ar.processFinish(result);
    }

    public Drawable fetchDrawable(ParseFile pf) {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = (InputStream) new URL(pf.getUrl()).getContent();
            return Drawable.createFromStream(is,null);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void processFinish(Drawable d) {
    appIconDrawable[i] = d; // i also tried testing appIconDrawable[1] = d and the app loaded with all blank images and then crashes
}
```

This is the interface, `AsyncResponse`:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(Drawable d);
}
```

LogCat (is there something else I should post?):

```
12-02 12:58:05.782: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at com.geekyouup.android.newton.StoreListViewActivity.processFinish(StoreListViewActivity.java:200)
12-02 12:58:05.782: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at com.geekyouup.android.newton.StoreListViewActivity$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(StoreListViewActivity.java:181)
12-02 12:58:05.782: E/AndroidRuntime(6598):     at com.geekyouup.android.newton.StoreListViewActivity$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(StoreListViewActivity.java:1)
12-02 12:58:14.481: D/IPPolicy(1343): updateImsNotification. ComponentName: ComponentInfo{com.geekyouup.android.newton/com.geekyouup.android.newton.StoreListViewActivity} tickerText null
12-02 12:58:14.511: D/IPPolicy(1343): updateImsNotification. ComponentName: ComponentInfo{com.geekyouup.android.newton/com.geekyouup.android.newton.StoreListViewActivity} tickerText null
12-02 12:58:15.512: D/IPPolicy(1343): updateImsNotification. ComponentName: ComponentInfo{com.geekyouup.android.newton/com.geekyouup.android.newton.StoreListViewActivity} tickerText null
12-02 12:58:16.383: I/ActivityManager(725): Process com.geekyouup.android.newton (pid 6598) (adj 0) has died.
```

Comment: Please don't repost questions. Wait for answers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not initializing the member variable `appIconDrawable`.

This line:

```
final Drawable[] appIconDrawable = new Drawable[ParseResult.size()];
```

Defines a local variable. If you want to initialize the member variable then it should be:

```
appIconDrawable = new Drawable[ParseResult.size()];
```

and I don't see a call to `queryAppIcon`, I'm guessing you are calling it somewhere...

Comment: Thanks! This was it. It no longers crashes. And yes, it is being called from somewhere. Do you have any idea why the images I'm loading are still blank though? They work fine when it's not through the AsyncTask method